# Composer is not loading my own psr-0 files

Tags: php, composer-php, psr-0

I can't seem to get composer to work with my own classes/files using the psr-0 autoload mechanism. Can anyone please shed some light as to why the below isn't working?

I'm getting the following output in my error log:

> PHP Fatal error: Class 'TestdirTest1' not found in
>   /home/webroot/bitlama/index.php on line 5

It does work If I uncomment the explicit require statement (index.php:2).

And if anybody is wondering - yes I have run composer install in the form of: 'php ../composer.phar install'.

This is my directory structure:

```
├── composer.json
├── index.php
├── testspacedir
│   └── Testdir
│       └── test1.php
└── vendor
    ├── autoload.php
    └── composer
        ├── autoload_classmap.php
        ├── autoload_namespaces.php
        ├── autoload_real.php
        └── ClassLoader.php
```

composer.json:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "Testdir\\": "testspacedir/"}
    }
}
```

test1.php:

```
<?php

namespace Testdir;

class Test1 {

    public function __construct()
    {
        echo "Woohoo Test1";
    }

}
```

index.php:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
//require 'testspacedir/Testdir/test1.php';

$test1 = new Testdir\Test1();
```

vendor/autoload.php:

```
<?php

// autoload.php @generated by Composer

require_once __DIR__ . '/composer' . '/autoload_real.php';

return ComposerAutoloaderInit7b4760e0f7ca9d6454dd2f098c374ba4::getLoader();
```

Comment: Have a look at the `vendor/composer/autoloader_namespaces.php`. This should contain a line with your namespace as array key and the correct folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My class file was named as `test1.php` instead of the required PSR-0 naming convention of `Test1.php`.

Answer (score 0):

You say it works because you removed `require 'testspacedir/Testdir/test1.php';` and that is correct.

Since you defined the namespace -> folder structure in the `autoload` in `composer.json`, the `vendor/autoload.php` handles the loading of these folder(s) for you.

Take a look inside that `vendor/autoload.php` file and you will see for yourself.

To sum it up, composer handles the autoloading of the files for you so you don't have to perform these includes. Here is a snippet from http://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading

> Note: Composer provides its own autoloader. If you don't want to use
>   that one, you can just include
>   vendor/composer/autoload_namespaces.php, which returns an associative
>   array mapping namespaces to directories.

Comment: I meant to say it ONLY works if I explicitly have that require statement. It doesn't work otherwise - I get a fatal error.

Comment: I am confused then, have you manually gone through the `autoload.php` and see if everything checks out and all the paths are set properly?

Comment: Not to sure to be quite honest. I've edit the original question with the contents of autoload.php

Comment: Follow the include trail as the actual autoload file doesn't help much :)